# R, igraph: Where is better to store names of vertices? + runtime measurements

Tags: r, performance, igraph

Well, I need to handle with large dense graphs in R. Also this graphs may have quite big names of vertices. I use `igraph` package and in general I have the following two possibilities:

1. store "original big names" in `name` attribute
2. store them, for example, in `realname` attribute and `name` attribute fill by ids

The thing is `igraph` can access to the vertex by its `name`, so I concern about the possible performance. For example, a larger `name` may require more overhead. However, I found the opposite using the code below.

**Idea**: measure random access to graph elements depending on the size of the `name` attribute

**Results**:

```
Name: Character Names >> Time difference of 3.435584 mins
Name: Character Ids   >> Time difference of 4.507384 mins
```

**Question**: Why do I get such a counterintuitive result and What is the best way to store names of vertices?

Thanks in advance!

**Code**:

```
library(igraph)

n   <- 50000
charIds  <- c()
verNames <- c()
g1 <- make_ring(n)
g2 <- make_ring(n)

for (i in 1:n) {
    verNames[i] <- paste("VeryVeryVeryLongAndStrangeName:", i, sep = "")
    charIds[i] <- as.character(i)
}

V(g1)$name  <- verNames
V(g2)$name  <- charIds

# -------- Test1: Begin -------- #
start1 <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:n) {
    ranNumber <- as.integer(runif(1, 1, n))
    try(V(g1)[verNames[ranNumber]])
}
end1 <- Sys.time()
cat("Name: Character Names >> ")
print (end1 - start1)
# -------- Test1: End -------- #

# -------- Test2: Begin -------- #
start2 <- Sys.time()
for (i in 1:n) {
    ranNumber <- as.integer(runif(1, 1, n))
    try(V(g2)[charIds[ranNumber]])
}
end2 <- Sys.time()
cat ("Name: Character Ids   >> ")
print (end2 - start2)
# -------- Test2: End -------- #
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the difference you are getting has more to do with the way the code is timed than with a significant difference in actual times.
The problem seems to be the granularity of `system.time`. It is not the best way to measure the running time of R code. Much better is to use a package such as package `microbenchmark`.

In what follows I have changed your code a little, starting with the number of vertices from 50000 to 500.

```
library(igraph)
library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

f <- function(g, charVec, rn){
    for (i in seq_along(rn)) {
        try(V(g)[charVec[ rn[i] ]])
    }
}

set.seed(9707)

n   <- 500
g1 <- make_ring(n)
g2 <- make_ring(n)

verNames <- paste("VeryVeryVeryLongAndStrangeName:", 1:n, sep = "")
charIds <- as.character(1:n)
ranNumber <- sample.int(n, n, TRUE)

V(g1)$name  <- verNames
V(g2)$name  <- charIds


mb <- microbenchmark(
    long = f(g1, verNames, ranNumber),
    short = f(g2, charIds, ranNumber),
    times = 100
)

mb
#Unit: seconds
#  expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  long 1.48296 1.560941 1.612141 1.599182 1.647836 1.892210   100
# short 1.48385 1.550512 1.629363 1.598392 1.642355 4.287886   100
```

As you can see, the times the same, except for an outlier that shows up in the short names graph access. And since a picture is worth a thousand words, `microbenchmark` includes a function to graph its results. (You will need package `ggplot2`.)

```
autoplot(mb)
```

[image]